# Reading Incoming IMAP Email Headers in Mule ESB

Tags: email, header, mule, esb

Our company is currently working with IBM to configure Mule to monitor a mailbox for email NDRs and then depending on the `Keyword:` in the email header process the bounced email.

I know next to nothing about Mule and it looks like the IBM colleagues are none the wiser.  I can see that the inbound NDRs have a header line called `Keywords:` but the Mule logs show no sign of it.  Logging has been enabled to output the `Keywords:` but it shows as `null`.

I am assuming that it needs to be configured somewhere as all the usual headers are showing up fine:

```
contentType=multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
fromAddress=Microsoft Outlook <MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36a@XXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com>
replyToAddresses=Microsoft Outlook <MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36a@XXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com>
sentDate=Thu Aug 11 12:04:30 BST 2016
subject=Undeliverable: About Number: 7000102920
toAddresses=BounceBack.Test@XXXXXXXXXX.com
```

I'm hitting a brick wall and keep going round in circles, so I'm hoping someone can point me to where the relevant configuration needs to be done, so I can inform the so called "experts".

---

Added in reponse to brazo's comment.  I've had to change some of the variables to depersonalise them but everything else is intact.  I don't really know any of these things, and have just fished it out of one of the files on the ESB server.

I have been told that outputting `#[message]` should show all the headers, but unfortunately `Keywords` is not being written.  I've double checked the email header in Outlook and it is definitely there.

```
<imaps:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="MailErrorMailBox" user="${esb.documentgenerationemaildeliveryfailure.mailbox.user}" password="${esb.documentgenerationemaildeliveryfailure.mailbox.password}" host="${esb.documentgenerationemaildeliveryfailure.mailbox.host}" port="${esb.documentgenerationemaildeliveryfailure.mailbox.port}" 
        connector-ref="imapsConnector" transformer-refs="returnAttachments" doc:description="Inbound for MailErrorMailBox" />
<logger level="DEBUG" />
<logger message="${msgId} #[flowVars['TransactID']] |#[flow.name]| Message from the email Service #[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

<logger message="${msgId} #[flowVars['TransactID']] |#[flow.name]| Contents retrieved from mail....batchName..#[message.inboundProperties['batchName']].....
        requestingSystem....#[message.inboundProperties['Return-Path']]...smtpAction...#[message.inboundProperties['smtpAction']]...smtpStatus..#[message.inboundProperties['smtpStatus']]...
        smtpDSNDeliveryStatus...#[message.inboundProperties['SMTPDSNDeliveryStatus']]....smtpDSNDeliveryReason...#[message.inboundProperties['SMTPDSNDeliveryReason']]"
        level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
<logger message="Message inbound Properties for keywords:: #[message.inboundProperties['Keywords:']] or the other one #[message.inboundProperties['Keywords']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />   
<logger message="${msgId} #[flowVars['TransactID']] |#[flow.name]| Contents retrieved from mail...
        Subject::#[message.inboundProperties['Subject']]...Keywords::#[message.inboundProperties['Keywords:']].. 
        Keywords:BatchName::#[message.inboundProperties['Keywords: batchName']]..Keywords: requestingSystem::#[message.inboundProperties['Keywords: requestingSystem']]"
        level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
<logger message="inbound Properties for keywords:: #[inboundProperties['Keywords']]...#[inboundProperties['Keywords:']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />  

<flow-ref name="EmailDeliveryStatusUpdateHndSubFlow" doc:name="EmailDeliveryStatusUpdateHndSubFlow Reference"
        doc:description="Refers to the flow where tranforms delivery status 
        messages retrieved from mail box, transforms into UpdateRequestMessage and puts this message into UpdateQueue" />

<exception-strategy ref="CommonExceptionStrategy" doc:name="EmailDeliveryStatusUpdateExceptionStrategy"
        doc:description="Exception strategy is used to handle exceptions in EmailDeliveryStatusUpdateHnd flow" />
```

---

Output of log:

```
    Message from the email Service 
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=631f9e20-5fb3-11e6-98ed-0050568411c3
  payload=java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList
  correlationId=<not set>
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
    startTimestamps={1-63236eb2-5fb3-11e6-98ed-0050568411c3:flowlike:MailErrorMailBoxFlow#[DocumentGenerationEmailDeliveryFailure-1.0.12-4677].imapsConnector.receiver.01=1470913474844}
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    0Headers={Content-Type=multipart/alternative; differences=Content-Type;
    boundary="5720b157-6ac6-4d83-966a-33ad74171d62", X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics=1;mailserver;9:cRRFeUAdYPRBiyTYpDTA5lQmVHBi1g/3iHOMtv6E8r0qbhKk7fk8HBM1xD7GbVZw+272bkKy6e8tvBhc1NkPLv4M8tuLo382CeCUdS+Ordq2qzHRnLTIRHe9WwX7PE+4g9M1PBhy25AzNn3YwpaCzJgVUHAza1jivZBbvNGwnbRggI0Lsb/uOS5MtBDU9GtfSO3v7pe02sQz9HHQuh7iSw==}
    1Headers={Content-Type=message/delivery-status, X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics=1;mailserver;9:cRRFeUAdYPRBiyTYpDTA5lQmVHBi1g/3iHOMtv6E8r0qbhKk7fk8HBM1xD7GbVZw+272bkKy6e8tvBhc1NkPLv4M8tuLo382CeCUdS+Ordq2qzHRnLTIRHe9WwX7PE+4g9M1PBhy25AzNn3YwpaCzJgVUHAza1jivZBbvNGwnbRggI0Lsb/uOS5MtBDU9GtfSO3v7pe02sQz9HHQuh7iSw==}
    2Headers={Content-Type=message/rfc822, X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics=1;mailserver;9:cRRFeUAdYPRBiyTYpDTA5lQmVHBi1g/3iHOMtv6E8r0qbhKk7fk8HBM1xD7GbVZw+272bkKy6e8tvBhc1NkPLv4M8tuLo382CeCUdS+Ordq2qzHRnLTIRHe9WwX7PE+4g9M1PBhy25AzNn3YwpaCzJgVUHAza1jivZBbvNGwnbRggI0Lsb/uOS5MtBDU9GtfSO3v7pe02sQz9HHQuh7iSw==}
    Authentication-Results=XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk; dkim=none (message not signed)
 header.d=none;XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk; dmarc=none action=none
 header.from=XXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com;
    Auto-Submitted=auto-replied
    Content-Language=en-US
    Content-Type=multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="22cf7e76-a186-4578-a350-dcf882b78a2c"
    Date=Thu, 11 Aug 2016 11:04:30 +0000
    From=Microsoft Outlook
    <MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36ab6ce41109e@XXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com>
    In-Reply-To=<260310942.53.1470913447307.JavaMail.user@server>
    List:Authentication-Results=[XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk; dkim=none (message not signed)
 header.d=none;XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk; dmarc=none action=none
 header.from=XXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com;]
    List:Auto-Submitted=[auto-replied]
    List:Content-Language=[en-US]
    List:Content-Type=[multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="22cf7e76-a186-4578-a350-dcf882b78a2c"]
    List:Date=[Thu, 11 Aug 2016 11:04:30 +0000]
    List:From=[Microsoft Outlook
    <MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36ab6ce41109e@XXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com>]
    List:In-Reply-To=[<260310942.53.1470913447307.JavaMail.user@server>]
    List:MIME-Version=[1.0]
    List:Message-ID=[<676ceca7-b6fd-46be-9e89-952a3953428f@mailserver.prd.prod.outlook.com>]
    List:Received=[from mailserver.prd.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.136) by
 mailserver.prd.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.136) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id
 15.1.549.15 via Mailbox Transport; Thu, 11 Aug 2016 11:04:31 +0000, from mailserver.prd.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.147) by
 mailserver.prd.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.136) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id
 15.1.549.15; Thu, 11 Aug 2016 11:04:30 +0000]
    List:References=[<260310942.53.1470913447307.JavaMail.user@server>]
    List:Return-Path=[<>]
    List:SpamDiagnosticOutput=[1:0]
    List:Subject=[Undeliverable: About Number: 7000102920]
    List:To=[<BounceBack.Test@XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk>]

    MIME-Version=1.0
    MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT=endpoint.imaps.AB.CD.999999.XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk
    Message-ID=<676ceca7-b6fd-46be-9e89-952a3953428f@mailserver.prd.prod.outlook.com>
    Received=from mailserver.prd.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.136) by
 mailserver.prd.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.136) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id
 15.1.549.15 via Mailbox Transport; Thu, 11 Aug 2016 11:04:31 +0000
    References=<260310942.53.1470913447307.JavaMail.user@server>
    Return-Path=<>
    SpamDiagnosticOutput=1:0
    To=<BounceBack.Test@XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk>

    bccAddresses=
    ccAddresses=
    contentType=multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="22cf7e76-a186-4578-a350-dcf882b78a2c"
    fromAddress=Microsoft Outlook <MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36ab6ce41109e@XXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com>
    replyToAddresses=Microsoft Outlook <MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36ab6ce41109e@XXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com>
    sentDate=Thu Aug 11 12:04:30 BST 2016
    subject=Undeliverable: About Number: 7000102920
    toAddresses=BounceBack.Test@XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    APPDYNAMICS_GUID=71d444d0-a663-4dba-8bf6-0469ff1d069f
    MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8
  SESSION scoped properties:
}
```

And the header seen in Outlook (note, the log output and the below header details are not of the same email as the log files have been lost, but they are of the same test I have been doing over and over again and therefore I can guarantee the `Keywords` header entry is there every time):

```
Received: from mailserver.prd.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.179) by
HE1PR03MB1481.prd.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.151) with Microsoft SMTP
Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id
15.1.549.15; Tue, 9 Aug 2016 10:37:42 +0000
Received: from XXX.protection.gbl (2a01:111:f400:7e04::142) by
mailserver.outlook.office365.com (2a01:111:e400:8040::51) with Microsoft
SMTP Server (version=TLS1_0, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384)
id 15.1.549.15 via Frontend Transport; Tue, 9 Aug 2016 10:37:42 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=fail (sender IP is 195.171.18.234)
smtp.mailfrom=XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk; XXXXXXXXXX.mail.onmicrosoft.com;
dkim=none (message not signed)
header.d=none;XXXXXXXXXX.mail.onmicrosoft.com; dmarc=none action=none
header.from=;
Received-SPF: Fail (protection.outlook.com: domain of XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk
does not designate 195.171.18.234 as permitted sender)
receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=195.171.18.234;
helo=edge.XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk;
Received: from edge.XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk (195.171.18.234) by
XXX.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.47.217.78) with Microsoft SMTP
Server (version=TLS1_0, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384) id
15.1.557.8 via Frontend Transport; Tue, 9 Aug 2016 10:37:43 +0000
Received: from server.gwd.grpinf.net (172.23.226.210) by
edge.XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk (172.23.245.41) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS)
id 14.3.210.2; Tue, 9 Aug 2016 11:37:33 +0100
Received: from uk-mgdirn-ap002.gwd.grpinf.net (172.23.245.28) by
server.gwd.grpinf.net (172.23.226.213) with Microsoft SMTP Server id
14.3.210.2; Tue, 9 Aug 2016 11:37:33 +0100
Received: from unknown (HELO dcn2dwal913) ([172.23.245.28])  by
uk-mgdirn-ap002.gwd.grpinf.net with ESMTP; 09 Aug 2016 11:37:34 +0100
Date: Tue, 9 Aug 2016 11:37:33 +0100
From: "[UAT] Test" <NO_REPLY>
To: revised NB <b4cbouncebacktest@XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk>
Message-ID: <1592434427.5.1470739053332.JavaMail.user@server>
Subject: About Number: 7000102920
Keywords: batchName=0567f0a36407435e98ca545c1349c0ce;requestingSystem=ABCD
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
        boundary="----=_Part_4_958412679.1470739053301"
Return-Path: BounceBack.Test@XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk
```

---

Following brazo's comments we have this flow:

```
    <flow processingStrategy="synchronous" name="MailErrorMailBoxFlow" doc:name="MailErrorMailBoxFlow" doc:description="This flow reads the mails from MailErrorMailBox 
and puts the delivery status message into UpdateReqQ">

<imaps:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="MailErrorMailBox" user="${esb.documentgenerationemaildeliveryfailure.mailbox.user}" password="${esb.documentgenerationemaildeliveryfailure.mailbox.password}" host="${esb.documentgenerationemaildeliveryfailure.mailbox.host}" port="${esb.documentgenerationemaildeliveryfailure.mailbox.port}" 
connector-ref="imapsConnector" disableTransportTransformer="true" doc:description="Inbound for MailErrorMailBox" />

<logger message="Received Payload: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<logger message="Received Message: #[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
<logger level="DEBUG" message="Payload as String: #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]"/>
<logger level="DEBUG" message="Data Type of Payload: #[message.getDataType]"/>

etc...
```

This produces (I've removed all the Exchange stuff because it was making it go over the body character count):

```
18-Aug-2016 13:10:40.479 INFO  DocumentGenerationEmailDeliveryFailure [DocumentGenerationEmailDeliveryFailure-1.0.15-4728].imapsConnector.receiver.02 processor.LoggerMessageProcessor correlationID: appDynamicHttpHeader: - Received Payload: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage@908e18b
18-Aug-2016 13:10:40.483 INFO  DocumentGenerationEmailDeliveryFailure [DocumentGenerationEmailDeliveryFailure-1.0.15-4728].imapsConnector.receiver.02 processor.LoggerMessageProcessor correlationID: appDynamicHttpHeader: - Received Message: 
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=c7ac74b0-653c-11e6-8b87-0050568411c3
  payload=javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
  correlationId=<not set>
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
    startTimestamps={1-c7b8a9b1-653c-11e6-8b87-0050568411c3:flowlike:DLGMailErrorMailBoxFlow#[DocumentGenerationEmailDeliveryFailure-1.0.15-4728].imapsConnector.receiver.02=1471522240476}
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    0Headers={Content-Type=multipart/alternative; differences=Content-Type;
    boundary="28acc557-a764-4ecf-9e77-16fa5f92c79b", 

    Authentication-Results=grp.co.uk; dkim=none (message not signed)
 header.d=none;grp.co.uk; dmarc=none action=none
 header.from=grp.onmicrosoft.com;
    Auto-Submitted=auto-replied
    Content-Language=en-US
    Content-Type=multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="c0871f9c-2c75-4842-8a17-8308e6a9b326"
    Date=Thu, 18 Aug 2016 12:10:33 +0000
    From=Microsoft Outlook
    <MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36ab6ce41109e@grp.onmicrosoft.com>
    In-Reply-To=<658849591.157.1471522231052.JavaMail.head@server>
    List:Authentication-Results=[grp.co.uk; dkim=none (message not signed)
 header.d=none;grp.co.uk; dmarc=none action=none
 header.from=grp.onmicrosoft.com;]
    List:Auto-Submitted=[auto-replied]
    List:Content-Language=[en-US]
    List:Content-Type=[multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="c0871f9c-2c75-4842-8a17-8308e6a9b326"]
    List:Date=[Thu, 18 Aug 2016 12:10:33 +0000]
    List:From=[Microsoft Outlook
    <MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36ab6ce41109e@grp.onmicrosoft.com>]
    List:In-Reply-To=[<658849591.157.1471522231052.JavaMail.head@server>]
    List:MIME-Version=[1.0]
    List:Message-ID=[<8ee0fb04-84c2-4355-8aba-8e85cbd608ac@XXX.prod.outlook.com>]
    List:Received=[from XXX.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.137) by
 XXX.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.136) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id
 15.1.549.15 via Mailbox Transport; Thu, 18 Aug 2016 12:10:33 +0000, from XXX.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.150) by
 XXX.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.137) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_0, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384) id
 15.1.549.15; Thu, 18 Aug 2016 12:10:33 +0000]
    List:References=[<658849591.157.1471522231052.JavaMail.head@server>]
    List:Return-Path=[<>]
    List:SpamDiagnosticOutput=[1:0]
    List:Subject=[Undeliverable: About Number: 5000102334]
    List:To=[<ST3@grp.co.uk>]

    MIME-Version=1.0
    MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT=endpoint.imaps.SM.FM.999171.grp.co.uk
    Message-ID=<8ee0fb04-84c2-4355-8aba-8e85cbd608ac@XXX.prod.outlook.com>
    Received=from XXX.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.137) by
XXX.prod.outlook.com (10.XXX.XXX.136) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id
 15.1.549.15 via Mailbox Transport; Thu, 18 Aug 2016 12:10:33 +0000
    References=<658849591.157.1471522231052.JavaMail.head@server>
    Return-Path=<>
    SpamDiagnosticOutput=1:0
    To=<ST3@grp.co.uk>

    bccAddresses=
    ccAddresses=
    contentType=multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="c0871f9c-2c75-4842-8a17-8308e6a9b326"
    fromAddress=Microsoft Outlook <MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36ab6ce41109e@grp.onmicrosoft.com>
    replyToAddresses=Microsoft Outlook <MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36ab6ce41109e@grp.onmicrosoft.com>
    sentDate=Thu Aug 18 13:10:33 BST 2016
    subject=Undeliverable: About Number: 5000102334
    toAddresses=ST3@grp.co.uk
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    APPDYNAMICS_GUID=68df660c-b5b3-4803-bd73-acbcb5a0fd42
    MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8
  SESSION scoped properties:
}
18-Aug-2016 13:10:40.488 DEBUG DocumentGenerationEmailDeliveryFailure [DocumentGenerationEmailDeliveryFailure-1.0.15-4728].imapsConnector.receiver.02 processor.LoggerMessageProcessor correlationID: appDynamicHttpHeader: - Payload as String: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage@908e18b
18-Aug-2016 13:10:40.492 DEBUG DocumentGenerationEmailDeliveryFailure [DocumentGenerationEmailDeliveryFailure-1.0.15-4728].imapsConnector.receiver.02 processor.LoggerMessageProcessor correlationID: appDynamicHttpHeader: - Data Type of Payload: null
```

Comment: Could you please share the Mule XML code that you wrote so far? Also it would be good to know what are you logging up there? Are you integrating with Outlook? Which transport are you using?

Comment: @brazo, I have updated the question with the code I've found (not written by me because this is not my area).  We are using IMAP to consume from O365 mailboxes.

Comment: And what is the content of that log output: "Message from the email Service #[message]"? #[message] will give you the complete incoming message with all headers, payload and properties. Could you paste that too? If there are no keywords if you log that right after the imap inbound endpoint they seem not to be part of what you actually receive.

Comment: @brazo, added everything to the question.  The emails in Outlook have the Keyword header entry, but the logs from Mule show no trace of it.  I've tried changing what we send as the Keyword to just "TEST123" but that doesn't come up either.

Comment: I reviewed the Mule example here and seems it is just pasted into your code: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/imap-transport-reference.
Please remove the transformer-refs which seems not to be necessary and also add the snippet #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)] into your logger which should print the payload correctly. Maybe the email is part of the payload and the Mule message you see is just the container for all messages queried. So your keywords might be inside the payload. 
If you use Anypoint Studio all of this is easy to find out using the Debug mode.

Comment: @brazo - Thanks for this! I have passed it onto the IBM people.  If it turns out to be right I am going to screw at them because they have spent weeks faffing around with this.

Comment: @brazo, we added that extra line and this is all it shows: 16-Aug-2016 14:37:06.650 DEBUG DocumentGenerationEmailDeliveryFailure [DocumentGenerationEmailDeliveryFailure-1.0.13-4711].imapsConnector.receiver.03 processor.LoggerMessageProcessor correlationID: appDynamicHttpHeader: - Payload as String: [javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler@3d4b5a64, javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler@1e1b7aac, javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler@1e12c1a5]

Comment: @brazo, I think we need to convert a bytearray to string... no clue how though.

Comment: There is a Byte Array to String converter in case you use the Mule Kernel (CE): https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/using-transformers . Mule EE offers DataWeave which is way more powerful: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave

Comment: Btw did you remove the attachments transformer ref from the connector configuration?

Comment: @brazo, I had asked the Mule developers to remove the attachments transformer, but not 100% if they have.  I will chase them to double check... I am just faffing around with this because they cannot figure it out.  In terms of what we are using, all I know is that we run 3.6.2 and they use AnyPoint Studio.

Comment: @brazo, I've updated the question with the latest flow and test results.  Really stuck here :(